# Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5

Tags: android, androidimageslider

I trying to use AndroidImageSlider library but getting this errors:

```
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could 
not resolve com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5.
```

Have this kind of dependencies in my build.gradle

```
implementation 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
implementation 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar        
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Try `File->Invalidate Caches and Restart->Invalidate and Restart`
2. If no luck try, `File->Other Settings->Default Settings->Build, Execution, Deployment->Build Tools->Gradle->Offline work` and uncheck it.

Comment: I just try clean and rebuild and its work ! Thanks mate.